# Encoding to base32 from the shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, shell, encoding

I'm looking to encode an input string to base32 encoding directly from the shell. I'm looking to do this in ubuntu, but I imagine flavor doesn't particularly matter here.

Are there any existing linux/unix tools out there to simply do this?

Something along the lines of:

```
-bash-3.2$ echo -n 'hello' | base32
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm, a quick package search doesn't give anything like a single, standalone utility.

On the other hand, it shows that there's an appropriate Perl library, and it's easy enough to whip up a quick perl script.  Something like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmime-base32-perl
```

And then a script like `base32enc.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MIME::Base32 qw( RFC );

undef $/;  # in case stdin has newlines
$string = <STDIN>;

$encoded = MIME::Base32::encode($string);

print "$encoded\n";
```

So:

```
$ echo -n "hello" | ./base32enc.pl
NBSWY3DP
```

The fairly sparse CPAN entry is: http://search.cpan.org/~danpeder/MIME-Base32-1.01/Base32.pm

So, a minor change will let you do decodes, also.

Answer (score 4):

It's installed by default in Ubuntu 16.04 as part of [coreutils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/coreutils):

```
$ which base32
/usr/bin/base32
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 27 2017, 12:15:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b32encode('hello')
'NBSWY3DP'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an improvement of cjc excellent answer  so we can have a `base32` utility which works similarly to `base64` in the way  we can encode and decode:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use MIME::Base32;
use strict;

undef $/;

my $string = <STDIN>;
my $changed;

if ( $ARGV[0] eq "-d" ){
        $changed = MIME::Base32::decode($string);
}else{
        $changed = MIME::Base32::encode($string); 
}

if ( $changed =~ /\n$/ ) {
    printf $changed;
}else{
    printf $changed . "\n";
}
```

Test:

```
$ base32 < <(echo -n 'abcdef')
MFRGGZDFMY
$ base32 -d < <(echo  'MFRGGZDFMY')
abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `perl-MIME-Base32.noarch`:

   ```
   yum install perl-MIME-Base32.noarch
   ```
2. Save the script in bas32 filename:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use MIME::Base32 qw( RFC );

   undef $/;  # in case stdin has newlines
   $ed=$ARGV[0];
   $string=$ARGV[1];
   if ($ed eq "-e")
   {
   $encoded = MIME::Base32::encode($string);
   print "$encoded\n";
   }
   elsif ($ed eq "-d")
   {
   $decoded = MIME::Base32::decode($string);
   print "$decoded\n";
   }
   else { print " please pass option also\n";
   exit;
   }

   chmod +x base32
   cp base32 /usr/bin/
   base32 -e string
   base32 -d "any encoded value"
   ```